# Non-Migration Database Modification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, sinatra

I'm in the relatively early stages of building a web application, but I know what the overall goals of it should be. I'm currently using rails (3) and I'm fully appreciating the benefits of rails.

However, one thing that I'd be able to do at one point is allow clients to add/remove some columns to the database on their own. These additional columns would be within templates that I would set up ("number" columns that with pre-set options for searching, querying, etc.)

Basically I'm wondering if that is possible to do in rails, or whether it is more or less necessary to switch to a lower-level platform since in many ways this idea violates rails conventions.

Answer (score 0):

i would never ever allow clients/users to mess with my database schema!!!!oneeleven

what you might consider is putting optional user-related properties into a serialized field or use document based data-store like mongoDB so that you are free from the constraint of "columns"

Comment: I know the feeling (its scary enough sometimes working with clients...) and thanks for the tip on MongoDB.